# Form Control Async validation issue

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-observables

I'm trying to implement an async validation on Angular2 but when I tried to input something for some reason the debounce doesn't work. It triggers multiple times depending on my input. Also on load my async validator will be triggered thus setting the status to pending so the infobox showing `checking...`

Here's how I implement it:

HTML:

```
 <div class="form-group d-flex col px-0">
   <label for="coupon" class="col-2">coupon_code:</label
    <div class="col-5 pl-4 pr-0">
     <input
      class="form-control"
      id="coupon"
      type="text"
      name="coupon"
      formControlName="coupon"
      autocomplete="off"
      />
 </div>
```

TS file

form:

```
initForm() {
    const email = '';
    const password = '';
    const password_confirmation = '';
    const doctor = '';
    // const license = '';
    const type = 'doctor';
    const company_id = '';
    const corporate_token = '';
    const doctorLastName = '';

    this.signUpForm = this.fb.group(
      {
        coupon: ['',[], this.couponAsyncValidation.bind(this)]
      },
      {
        validator: this.signupFormValidator(),
      }
    );
  }
```

async validation code:

```
 couponAsyncValidation(control: FormControl): Promise<any | null> | Observable<any | null> {
     return new Promise( (res, rej) => {
      control.valueChanges.pipe(
        debounceTime(2000),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        switchMap(value => this.userService.couponChecker(value)),
        map( (q) => q ),
        first()
      ).subscribe(
        (d) => { 
        console.log(d)
         d.is_coupon_valid ? res(null) : res({invalid: true})
        }
      )
    })
  }
```

`couponAsyncValidation` will be triggered on load and the status is just pending even though I haven't touched the input.

### Update

I managed to work the status. I've checked if the status and pending and if it's dirty.

The problem left is the debounceTimer not working

**UPDATE**
I think I'm missing a observable function. what do you think?

**UPDATE**
heres an image of the request being sent after 2secs

### [image]

any idea why debounce not working?

**UPDATE**

This is working now with the help of @jarek.

here is the full code of the async validation

```
import { AbstractControl, AsyncValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
import { switchMap, map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { UserService } from '../user/services/user.service';
import { Observable, timer, of } from 'rxjs';

export class AsyncValidator {
  static couponValidator(miliSec: number, service: UserService): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<any | null> => {
      return timer(miliSec).pipe(
        switchMap(() => {
          if ( control.value ) {
            return service.couponChecker(control.value);
          }
          // this one is needed because for some reason on loading, the signup page
          // will immediately trigger this async call which sends a request to the backend
          // even though user has not inputted anything.
          // then sets the status of the form to pending thus resulting to an invalid form
          return of({is_coupon_valid: true});
        }),
        map( (res) =>  res.is_coupon_valid ? null : res )
      );
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: The async validator is called **every time** the value changes. So, every time the value changes, you create a new observable and subscribe to it. And this observble emits every time the value changes.

Comment: @JBNizet i know that already. sorry if my question is not clear. but why is it happening even though I set a `debounceTime` it should prevent it from casting until the set time has passed

Comment: I missed the call to first().

Answer (score 0):

I have a somewhat similar situation, except my async validator is on the form directly... the code is below but it won't be an exact match for what you need..  I suspect your core problem is that your subscribing to your control value changes which you shouldn't need to do since setting it up as a validator should already cause that validator to be called whenever the value changes.

```
validateExists(control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
{
    return timer(500).pipe(
            switchMap(() =>
                this.service.checkThingExists(control.value.value1, control.value.value2).pipe(
                    tap(() => setTimeout(() => this.isValid.emit(this.form.get('parcel').valid))),
                    map(valid => (valid ? null : { notFound: true }))
                )
            )
        );
}
```

Comment: If I wont pipe the value changes then how would you get the value or input from the user as they type?

Comment: The input parameter to the validation function has the control which has the value. So you just do control.value.  Your function is going to be called everytime the input changes because you set it up as a validator.  So you don't need to add another layer that catches the value changes.

Comment: i get you. that was first solution. but since this is async validation im calling a http request everytime there is a keyboard hit or input. so im trying to use `valueChanges` because it's an observable so I can just pipe it and add a debounceTime operator from rxjs so it would prevent the request everytime theres a keyboard hit.

Comment: In the example I posted above I'm using timer(500) to achieve a similar thing and I still don't need to subscribe to valueChanges.  Timer is an RxJs function as well.